# Runtime crash - ebook app with gesture listener and image share

Tags: java, android, crash, runtime, gesture

i am new to android and i am creating an ebook app that uses the gesture listener and share image. The code doesn't show that anything is wrong, but the app crashes.
Can someone help me to figure out what was i missing?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements android.view.View.OnClickListener  {

ImageView page;
ImageView sound;
ImageView share;
View v; 
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
private String currentPage="ap";
private int currentPageNumber=1;
private MediaPlayer pageTurn;
private MediaPlayer background;
private String key = "com.pavle.ebook.key";
private String keyPlay = "com.pavle.ebook.play";
private int isPlaying = 0;
SharedPreferences pref;
SharedPreferences play;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    sound = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Sound);
    share = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Share);



    //Initialize mediaplayer for pageturn and background
    pageTurn = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.page_turn);
    background = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.background);

    /*//Set oppacity to the sound image and the share image
    AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.75F, 0.75F);
    alpha.setDuration(0); // Make animation instant
    alpha.setFillAfter(true); // Tell it to persist after the animation ends
    // And then on your layout
    sound.startAnimation(alpha);
    share.startAnimation(alpha);*/

    //Set click listener for the views
    sound.setOnClickListener(this);
    share.setOnClickListener(this);

    //Load saved page number and isPlaying state
    pref = this.getSharedPreferences("com.pavle.ebook", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    play = this.getSharedPreferences("com.pavle.ebook", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    currentPageNumber=pref.getInt(key,1);
    isPlaying = play.getInt(keyPlay, 0);

    //Set background music if isPlaying is 0
    if(isPlaying==0){
        sound.setImageResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
        background.setLooping(true);
        background = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.background);
        background.start();
        background.setVolume(75, 75);
    }
    else
        sound.setImageResource(R.drawable.sound_off);

    //Set the page equal to the page number
    page = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Page);
    currentPage="ap"+currentPageNumber;

    //First get the resource Id with the string
    int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(currentPage, "drawable", "com.pavle.ebook");
    page.setImageResource(resId);
    page.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);



    //Set up gesture detector
     gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new MyGestureDetector());
        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };

    page.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    page.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);



}

class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    final ViewConfiguration vc = ViewConfiguration.get(getBaseContext());
    final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = vc.getScaledPagingTouchSlop();
    final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = vc.getScaledMinimumFlingVelocity();
    final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH= vc.getScaledTouchSlop();

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                pageTurn = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.page_turn);
                if(pageTurn.isPlaying())
                    pageTurn.stop();
                if(isPlaying==0)
                pageTurn.start();
                if(currentPageNumber++<=86){
                    //Page number increases and loads onto the imageView
                  currentPage="ap"+currentPageNumber;
                  int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(currentPage, "drawable", "com.pavle.ebook");
                  page.setImageResource(resId);
                  page.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                }
                else{
                    //If it's the last page that is loading, page number is 87 and it will stay that way
                    page.setImageResource(R.drawable.ap87);
                    page.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                    currentPageNumber=87;
                }
                pref.edit().putInt(key,currentPageNumber).apply(); 

              //left to right swap
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                pageTurn = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.page_turn);
                if(pageTurn.isPlaying())
                    pageTurn.stop();
                if(isPlaying==0)
                pageTurn.start();
                if(--currentPageNumber>1){
                    //Page number decreases and loads onto the imageView
                      currentPage="ap"+currentPageNumber;
                      int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(currentPage, "drawable", "com.pavle.ebook");
                      page.setImageResource(resId);
                      page.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                  }
                  else{
                      //The page number cannot be less than 1
                    page.setImageResource(R.drawable.ap1);
                    page.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                    currentPageNumber=1;
                  }
                pref.edit().putInt(key,currentPageNumber).apply(); 
                return true;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }

        @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
          return true;
    }
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.Sound:
            //TODO Create a persistant variable to stop all sounds or turn them on
            if(isPlaying==0){
                isPlaying=1;
                sound.setImageResource(R.drawable.sound_off);
                if(background.isPlaying())
                    background.stop();
                if(pageTurn.isPlaying())
                    pageTurn.stop();
            }
            else {
                isPlaying=0;
                sound.setImageResource(R.drawable.sound_on);
                if(background.isPlaying())
                    background.stop();
                    background.setLooping(true);
                    background.setVolume(75, 75);
                    background = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.background);
                    background.start();
            }
            play.edit().putInt(keyPlay, isPlaying).apply();
            break;
        case R.id.Share:
            currentPage="ap"+currentPageNumber;
            int resId = getResources().getIdentifier(currentPage, "drawable", "com.pavle.ebook");
            Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId);
            Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            share.setType("image/jpeg");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            icon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "temporary_file.jpg");
            try {
                f.createNewFile();
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                fo.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {                       
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/temporary_file.jpg"));
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));

            break;

    }

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    //Load saved page number and isPlaying state
        pref = this.getSharedPreferences("com.pavle.ebook", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        play = this.getSharedPreferences("com.pavle.ebook", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        currentPageNumber=pref.getInt(key,1);
        isPlaying = play.getInt(keyPlay, 0);
        pageTurn = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.page_turn);
        background = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.background);
        background.setLooping(true);
    if(isPlaying==0){
        if(background.isPlaying())
            background.stop();
        background.setVolume(75, 75);
        background = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.background);
        background.start();
    }


}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    if(background.isPlaying())
        background.stop();
    if(pageTurn.isPlaying())
        pageTurn.stop();
    background.release();
    pageTurn.release();
}
```

When i run it on the emulator, it doesn't even start and gives me the java.lang.RuntimeExeption: Unable to start activity...
But it's runnable on the phone, and crashes sometimes for no reason.
Thanks!
P.S.
Here is my log

```
02-09 13:15:42.285: D/skia(750): --- decoder->decode returned false
02-09 13:15:42.285: D/AndroidRuntime(750): Shutting down VM
02-09 13:15:42.285: W/dalvikvm(750): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
02-09 13:15:42.296: I/dalvikvm(750): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pavle.ebook/com.pavle.ebook.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class <unknown>
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at com.pavle.ebook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  ... 11 more
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  ... 25 more
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:109)
02-09 13:15:42.385: E/AndroidRuntime(750):  ... 28 more
```

Comment: It would be useful to see your LogCat

Comment: Anyway, it jumps in my eyes the funny syntax you used to get the resource identifiers... The error could be there. Please have a deep read at the [reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: When does it crash? What is the stacktrace?

Comment: @ArtooDetoo Here is my log cat, and i have look through it and still i don't know where the problem could be, but it crashes.

Comment: @FD_ It crashes when i start the activity on the emulator and crashes in the middle of the program when on the phone.